# hide "show more" when all data is displayed

Tags: reactjs

I have following code:

```
    function SolutionsSection({solutions}) {
      const mainSolutions = solutions.slice(0, 4);
      const restSolutions = solutions.slice(4);
      const [isShown, setShow] = useState(false);
       return (
        <div>
          <SolutionSectionBox
            isShown={isShown}
            mainSolutions={mainSolutions}
            restSolutions={restSolutions}
          />
           {/*below is my button component*/}
          <SolutionsSectionAllServices
            setShow={setShow}
            isShown={isShown}
          />
      </div>
     );
    }
```

I have 4 "solution" information in backend (in the future there will be 9 solutions information). I can successfully fetch that informations and pass to my "SolutionsSection" component as you see.

I divided information in two pieces. First is "mainSolutions" which will show first 4 solutions. Second  one is my "restSolutions" which will load rest solutions by clicking on "SolutionsSectionAllServices".
with useState I deciding show or hide my restSolutions

Now my question is, how can I hide my button when I have only 4 solutions, I don't need my button because there is nothing to show more as all solutions was displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
{restSolutions > 0 ? <YourButtonComponent> : null}
```